# Problems with json string at d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

Some js:

```
var cityDivisionJSON = '[\
{"city":"Челябинск","percentage":"66.67"},\
{"city":"Аша","percentage":"16.67"},\
{"city":"Бакал","percentage":"16.67"},\
{"city":"Верхний Уфалей","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Еманжелинск","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Златоуст","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Карабаш","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Карталы","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Касли","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Катав-Ивановск","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Коркино","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Куса","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Кыштым","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Магнитогорск","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Миасс","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Миньяр","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Нязепетровск","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Сатка","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Сим","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Снежинск","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Трехгорный","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Троицк","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Усть-Катав","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Чебаркуль","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Южноуральск","percentage":"0"},\
{"city":"Юрюзань","percentage":"0"}\
]';
    root=JSON.parse(cityDivisionJSON);
    var arcs=group.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","arc")
        .on("mouseover",toggleArc)
        .on("mouseleave",toggleArc)
        .append("path")
        .attr("d",arc)
        .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.data.percentage);});
        group
        .append("circle")
        .style("fill","white")
        .attr("r",radius-20);
```

It says: data is not defined

Comment: There is no data. It should be root, as you have the parsed json stored in root

Comment: Thanx man, you can answer question!

Comment: Why are you putting JSON notation directly in a JavaScript application only to immediately parse it? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root = JSON.parse(cityDivision);
var arcs= d3.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(root))
        .enter()
```

You don't have `data` variable anywhere, that's why `.data(pie(data))`
 gives you error that data is undefined.

Replace it with `.data(pie(root))`.

Similarly in d3.js, there is no `group.selectAll`. Instead use `d3.selectAll()`.

This should fix your issues